# Laravel - javascript not working but no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, localization

I am now trying to use javascripts in my project. I searched all this morning on the Internet, and found nothing really clear about Laravel and Javascript.

Can somebody please **explain how exactly** (or link me from a known real example), can we make **javascripts** working on a Laravel project ? Thanks

Here's what i tried :

**template_mynet.blade.php**

```
...
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/bootstrap.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/accueil_hover.js') }}
...
```

**accueil.blade.php**

```
@extends('template_mynet')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with data-trigger</a>
        <a id="popoverOption" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title">Popup with option trigger</a>
    </div>
@stop
```

**accueil_hover.js**

```
$('#popoverData').popover();
$('#popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" })
```

**Where are my js files ?**

```
/public/assets/js
```

**What are my files ?**

```
accueil_hover.js
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.min.js
jquery-2-1-1.js
npm.js
```

Links are here, but the hovering is not working !
This code is from the example linked here :
http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your javascript in a document ready function. You javascript code won't work because the document isn't fully loaded yet.

change the javascript code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popoverData').popover();
    $('#popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

If this is still not working, please provide the full html output of your site and any console errors.

Comment: It is working. 
What is this function ? Can you detail a little more about it please ? I'm curious :)

Comment: This function executes the code inside when the rest of the document is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird problem though. The title of the question is the exact same thing but I had document ready function. The culprit was something else and it fixed by commenting out

> app.js

asset.